# Reference Page of Float Object only if Page isn't actual page

Tags: cross-referencing, conditionals

Is it possible to tell LaTeX only use \pageref if the referenced object isn't on actual page?

```
if \pageref{fig:hello_world} != self.page then
  \pageref{fig:hello_world}
end
```

Comment: Do you know package `varioref` (and `cleveref`)? `varioref` adds `\pageref` into the reference, if the figure or table is more than one page away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think perhaps you might like the [`varioref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/varioref) and/or the [`cleveref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/cleveref) packages

**`varioref`**

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varioref}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Here is a reference to Table \vref{tab:thispage}. 
  \item Here's a reference to Table \vref{tab:nextpage}.
\end{itemize}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    1 & 2
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table}
  \label{tab:thispage}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{20}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    1 & 2
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table}
  \label{tab:nextpage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

`cleveref`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% each of the following has two versions
%   \crefname{environmentname}{singular}{plural}, to be used mid-sentence
%   \Crefname{environmentname}{singular}{plural}, to be used at the beginning of a sentence

% standard environments
\crefname{table}{Table}{Tables}
\Crefname{table}{Table}{Tables}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Here is a reference to  \vref{tab:thispage}. 
  \item Here's a reference to \vref{tab:nextpage}.
\end{itemize}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    1 & 2
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table}
  \label{tab:thispage}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{20}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    1 & 2
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table}
  \label{tab:nextpage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `refcount` package to get the page number of the reference.  Then you can use the `xifthen` package to do a comparison of integer values.  You can get the value of the current page with the `\value{page}` command.  In the MWE below, you can comment or uncomment the `\clearpage` to demonstrate the difference in behavior.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Testing}\label{fig:test}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{temp}
\end{figure}
%Uncomment the clearpage command to get the pageref to print
%\clearpage
\ifthenelse{\getpagerefnumber{fig:test}=\value{page}}{}{\pageref{fig:test}}

\end{document}
```

You could now simplify things by changing the `pageref` command, so that you could can use pageref like normal, but it would run your conditional code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\let\originalPageref\pageref
\renewcommand{\pageref}[1]{\ifthenelse{\getpagerefnumber{#1}=\value{page}}{}{\originalPageref{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Testing}\label{fig:test}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{temp}
\end{figure}
%Uncomment the clearpage command to get the pageref to print
%\clearpage
\pageref{fig:test}

\end{document}
```